# Linear Regression using Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, linear-regression, relu

I am working on a regression problem with the following sample training data .

[image]

As shown I have an input of only 4 parameters with only one of them changing which is Z so the rest have no real value while an output of 124 parameters denoted from O1 to O124 
Noting that O1 changes with a constant rate of 20 [1000 then 1020 then 1040 ...] while O2 changes with a different rate which is 30 however still constant and same applies for all the 124 outputs ,all changes linearily in a constant way.

I believed it's a trivial problem and a very simple neural network model will reach a 100% accuracy on testing data but the results were the opposite.

- I reached 100% test accuracy using a linear regressor and 99.99997% test accuracy using KNN regressor
- I reached 41% test data accuracy in a 10 layered neural network using relu activation while all the rest activation functions failed and shallow relu also failed
- Using a simple neural network with linear activation function and no hidden layers I reached 92% on the test data

My Question is how can I get the neural network to get 100% on test data like the linear Regressor? 
It is supposed that using a shallow network with linear activation to be equivilant to the linear regressor but the results are different ,am I missing something ?

Comment: 10 layers of course isn't shallow I mean I tried another model with 1 or 2 hidden layers , and I need to use a Neural network not a linear regression because of some constraint on me by my work team lead

Comment: That's a pointless constraint if linear regression produces near-perfect results.

Answer (score 0):

If you use linear activation a deep model is in principle the same as a linear regression / a NN with 1 layer. E.g a deep NN with linear activation the prediction is given as y = W_3(W_2(W_1 x))), which can be rewritten as y = (W_3 (W_2 W_1))x, which is the same as y = (W_4 x), which is a linear Regression.

Given that check if your NN without a hidden layer converges to the same parameters as your linear regression. If this is not the case then your implementation is probably wrong. If this is the case, then your larger NN probably converges to some solution to the problem, where the test accuracy is just worse. Try different random seeds then.